# How to pass the value of a button to Flask Python function

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

Am I able to use the `request` object to do this? This button is not a form button.

My html file is called `display.html` and looks like so:

```
<table style="width:90%">

        <tr>
            <th> pluginid </th>
            <th>name </th>
            <th> exploitavailable</th>
            <th>severity </th>

        </tr>


    {% for element in elements %}
    <tr>
        <td> <button onclick="location.href='display.html';" type="button" value="{{element.split(" ",1)[0]}}" name="{{element.split(" ",1)[0]}}"> {{ element.split(" ",1)[0]}} </button></td>
        <td> {{element.split("\t",1)[0]}} </td>
        <td> {{element.split("\t",2)[1]}} </td>
        <td> {{element.split("\t",3)[2]}} </td>

    </tr>

    {% endfor %}

    </table>
```

my python code looks like so:

```
@app.route("/display.html",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def display():
    return render_template("display.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8898)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `{{element.split(" ",1)[0]}}` is the id of your plugin.

What you can do is is make a route for the plugin:

```
@app.route('/plugin_details/<int:plugin_id>')
def plugin_details(plugin_id):
    details = get_some_details(plugin_id)
    return render_template('plugin_details.html', details=details)
```

and then link to this page in the button using:

`<button onclick="window.location='{{url_for('plugin_details', plugin_id=element.split(" ",1)[0])}}';">Visit Page Now</button>`